# regex for matching 9-23 digits with any number of spaces or dashes inbetween

Tags: regex

I've tried the following regex, but it appears that nested "[]" are not allowed.

`[\d[\s-]*]{9-23}`

Comment: Is it OK to allow dashes or spaces before the first number, or after the last (ie: is 123456789- a match?)? And by "spaces" do you mean any whitespace (including, for example, tabs)?

Answer (score 6):

You're on the right track, what you're looking for is probably:

```
(\d[\s-]*){8,22}\d
```

- a digit
- followed by any number of whitespace/dash
- 8-22 times
- followed by the final digit

Comment: @Bryan: How? `123-` is only four characters long, so it won't match the `{9-23}` condition.

Comment: that will match '123456789-', which is not something that should match (if I understand the problem correctly)

Comment: @CanSpice: I realized my mistake shortly after I wrote it. You are correct that "123-" won't match, but "123456789-" will match.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you don't want to match leading or trailing spaces and dashes, so the pattern that I think will work is:

```
^\d([- ]*\d){8,22}$
```

That is: one digit, followed by between 8 and 22 groups of zero or more dashes or spaces followed by a single digit.

Another solution which might be more obvious is this two-step solution:

1. match against \d[-\d ]+\d to make sure you have a string of digits, spaces and dashes which both begins and ends with at least one digit
2. strip out just the digits and count how many you have

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this:

```
([0-9][ -]*){9,23}
```

This regular expression is too short of an answer so here's my favorite

Comment: that will match '123456789-', which is not something that should match (if I understand the problem correctly)

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you might consider splitting it into two steps. In C#, for example, you could do something like this.

```
Regex.Match(Regex.Replace(str, "[ -]", ""), @"^\d{9,23}")
```

This is two string operations, so of course there may be a performance penalty if that matters to you. But it may be more readable for the next guy.